# mysql if statement failing, not sure how to fix

Tags: mysql, if-statement

Currently I have this statement

```
IF(0.5 < SELECT (FLOOR(10*RAND()*pResourcium) AS TestVar FROM siegeverse.rooms rm) AS T))
THEN SELECT 'TEST'
```

Any idea why it is failing?  Trying to get it to output test for each row if the selected element is greater than 0.5

Thanks!

Comment: And why you think this should work? See [`mysql IF statement syntax`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/if.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SELECT statement in such scalar comparison contexts should return only one row. In your case, it might be returning multiple rows and so is failing. The following rewritten query is close to what you are interested in:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT
         CASE 
             WHEN (FLOOR(10*RAND()*pResourcium) >= 0.5 THEN 'TEST'
             ELSE NULL
         END AS TestVar
     FROM 
         siegeverse.rooms rm
    ) AS A
WHERE A.TestVar IS NOT NULL)
THEN
     <run the stored procedure>
```

Comment: does not work, what I really want to do is run a Proc if the statement I wrote is true

Comment: You can wrap this in an IF EXISTS statement and run your procedure, as updated in the response.